# How to reduce three query to one in multiple output template?

Tags: php

I would like to publish 7 posts from the same category but embedded in different DIV or UL.

How could I simplify this code?

```
<?php
$query01 = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'offset'=> 0, 'post_type' => array('product') );
$query02 = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'offset'=> 1, 'post_type' => array('product') );
$query03 = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'offset'=> 4, 'post_type' => array('product') );
?>

<div class="class news">
<ul class="280">
get_posts( $query01 ) -> FOREACH WITH ONE POST
</ul>
</div>

<div class="class editorial">
<ul class="650">
get_posts( $query02 ) -> FOREACH WITH THREE POST
</ul>
</div>

<div class="class images">
<ul class="980">
get_posts( $query03 ) -> FOREACH WITH THREE POST
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

query for all posts at once and set a counter variable to check where you are in the loop.

```
$products = get_posts(
    array( 
        'numberposts' => 7,
        'post_type' => array('product')
    )
);
$count = 1;
foreach( $products as $product ):
    if( $count == 1 ):
        // first post
    elseif( $count > 1 && $count < 5 ):
        // two - four
    else:
        // four +
    endif;
    $count++;
endforeach;
```

EDIT- using your markup:

```
$products = get_posts(
    array( 
        'numberposts' => 7,
        'post_type' => array('product')
    )
);

?>
<div class="class news">
<ul class="280">
<?php
$count = 1;
foreach( $products as $product ):
    if( $count == 2 ):
        ?>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="class editorial">
        <ul class="650">
        <?php
    elseif( $count == 5 ):
        ?>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="class images">
        <ul class="980">
        <?php
    endif;

    echo '<li>post</li>';
    $count++;
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that. But as you look at the code you notice I have  three different DIVs for the three groups of posts. If I use the code you suggest also DIVs will be iterated.

Comment: it just comes down to how you count it- if it's the second post, close the first container and open the second, if it's the fifth post, close the second container and open the third.

Comment: @Francesco see edit above

Comment: Thank You Milo. The code is clear now and it works. Waiting for a more straightforward solution (in long snippets of code identify the sections is very hard), I will otherwise accept your answer.